# How to have a wider spectrum of FFT at LTspice?

Tags: noise, ltspice, emc, common-mode, fft

I've used the FFT analysis tool to see the spectrum of DM and CM EMI noise in the range of 150K to 30MHz.

But the analysis stops at about 3MHz automatically and there is no option to set the max and min frequencies. how can I have the spectrum at the desired frequency range (150k~30MHz)?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you .tran time steps are not fine enough. Did you set the max time step option in the .tran settings ?

Comment: @tobalt, I didn't define it at all. what is the recommended value? BTW, the Run time would be very high with for example 100ns time step.

Comment: Well for 1 GHz Nyquist frequency you would need 500 ps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing an AC analysis in LT spice then you need to change the max sweep frequency in the .AC statement.

If you're doing a .trans analysis and converting it with the fft later then you need to increase the time resolution.